# Simple skewed Gaussian

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, approximation-theory

I recently reported this on Quora but I'd like to share it here too to try to get more people to give their opinions about this. Basically I designed a simple equation for skewed Gaussian curves.

For context: lately I’ve been doing enzyme activity experiments, and when testing the activity of my enzyme at different pH values I came across this data trend. I tried to fit the points to a Gaussian curve, but the fit felt off. ([Image](https://i.imgur.com/OxMSfuU.png))

It looks more like a skewed distribution, so I tried to find an equation to improve my fit, but the equations for a skewed normal distribution ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution)) are complicated and impractical to apply when using a software like Origin or GraphPad (to my knowledge at least). So I did a little more digging and I came across [a paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280939732_Optimization_of_Active_Muscle_Force-Length_Models_Using_Least_Squares_Curve_Fitting) showcasing a simple equation. I have no idea where this equation came from, but it kinda worked, so I played a little bit with the parameters of that equation, optimized it, and ended up with this other equation. And it works! The fit is great! ([Image](https://i.imgur.com/6pVRLlV.png))

$$y = y_0 + A \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x - x_0}{w + a \cdot (x - x_0)}\right)^2}$$

The idea is that it’s like a modified version of a typical Gaussian equation, but including parameter “a” for skewness. When a=0 you get your usual symmetric Gaussian graph, a<0 makes the graph negatively skewed (to the left), and a>0 positively skewed (to the right). The rest of the parameters (“x0”, “y0”, “A”, “w”) are the same as a typical Gaussian curve. I also made a simple diagram showcasing the role each parameter plays in the equation: ([Image](https://i.imgur.com/KKJVZw7.png))

I also made a Desmos sheet so you can play with the parameters and figure it out yourselves: [Simple skewed Gaussian](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gokr63ciym).

It’s not really perfect like the more complicated equations, the graph isn’t really flat besides the peak, it’s got an inflexion point and another curve going on after it but I don’t think it’s relevant since the skewness is generally not large enough to affect the fit. The point is that it’s good enough for fits, it’s a simple equation appropiate for these cases, and I wanted to report it here, in case someone has the same problem as me and is looking for a simple solution. I hope this equation proves useful to anyone dealing with skewed Gaussian curves in their experiments!

Hope I explained myself well enough, and I welcome any suggestions and comments. I'd love to hear the opinions of people who have more knowledge than I do on this topic. Thank you for taking the time to read about my findings!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I intended to share a my equation for fitting skewed Gaussian curves, and while I didn't explicitly pose a specific question, I was hoping to start a discussion and hear from others who might have experience or insights into this topic. So if anyone has any suggestions, thoughts or feedback on the equation itself, or if anyone else has encountered similar challenges with skewed Gaussian curves in their experiments or research, I'd love to hear how you've approached fitting and modeling such data.

Comment: This might be a convolution of a normal distribution with some other distribution. These arise when your underlying variable is a sum of two variables, one of which is normal and the other some  other kind of variable.

Comment: Well the variable under investigation is pH, I guess it's a opretty straightforward and well-defined parameter. If there was something else it would go unaccounted for and I would have no way of knowing it or including it in the fit. That's why I took this approach to fit my data with a simple equation.

Comment: looks like a truncated gaussian.Does the sudden drop even make sense biologically?

Comment: My supervisor said it does, but I'm not sure, I haven't found the evidence to back it up in articles